# Linux Samba 4.7 Server -> Windows 7/10 Client creates file -> execute is set -> "store dos attributes = no" has no effect

Tags: permissions, samba

0 to run a Samba 4.7 Server and openLDAP for Authentication. Several Windows 7/10 Clients connect and create files and folders.

I have the following Problem:

1.) If the LDAP user `john` touches a file while connected to the sambaServer with SSH the file Permissions are correct ( **execute** bit is **not set** for files):

```
john@sambaServer:/data/projects/general/john> touch testExecutePermission.dat
john@sambaServer:/data/projects/general/john> ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 john gast 0 Nov 30 18:44 testExecutePermission.dat
john@v:/data/projects/general/john>
```

2.) If the user john uses his windows explorer to create a file :
[image]

The new file is **executable** for owner, group and others:

```
john@sambaServer:/data/projects/general/john> ll
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 john gast 0 Nov 30 18:44 testExecutePermission.dat
-rwxrwxr-x+ 1 john gast 0 Nov 30 18:47 New Text Document.txt
```

From the  [Samba Documentation](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html#STOREDOSATTRIBUTES) I understand that the owner, group and others execute bits are used by samba to store three DOS attributes (SYSTEM, HIDDEN, ARCHIVE).

To control if the execute bits are used the `store dos attributes` parameter is used. I
f I understand the usage of this parameter correctly `store dos attributes = yes` means something like:

*"Try to store the DOS attributes in an extended attribute in the UNIX filesystem instead of the execute bits of the file."*

3. So I set `store dos attributes = yes` and tried a before and after:

   `/etc/samba/smb.conf`
       `[global]`
   `create mask = 0660`
   `directory mask = 770`
           `...`
           `store dos attributes = yes`
           `...`

**Results in command line with [getfattr](https://linux.die.net/man/1/getfattr) command:**

```
`sambaServer:/data/  getfattr windowsFileStoreDosAttributes_no.txt`   
`user.SAMBA_PAI`

`sambaServer:/data/  getfattr windowsFileStoreDosAttributes_yes.txt`  
`user.DOSATTRIB`
`user.SAMBA_PAI`
```

3.1 So the good news is, yes the extended UNIX filesystem attribute `user.DOSATTRIB` is set. But the files are still executable.

3.2 The Parameters `map archive / readonly /h idden / system` are apparently not used if `store dos attributes` is set. But I also tried all combinations of setting them.

Does anyone have an Idea why the execute bits are still set ?

Comment: What is your `create mask` set to in your `smb.conf` file for the shares?

Comment: create mask = 0660
directory mask = 770